# Parsing xml with lxml only certain depth

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I am working with documents that contain valid xml only to a certain depth once that depth is reached there might be invalid xml however one can be sure that inside the invalid text the previous xml tags won’t occur. (I guess one could assume there is binary inside )

Therefore I need to parse the document only to a certain depth the rest should be handled as text even if it might contain other tags.

Is this possible with lxml, writing my own lexer would definitely be an overkill

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a short example of the xml and your expected output from that?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar issue, to used with [xsData](https://xsdata.readthedocs.io/en/v20.1/), to limit the deserialisation only to elements I would be interested in. The deque example comes from the [LXML api](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/doc/api.txt). I have added the depth, and use the copied parent for reconstruction.

```py
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Element
from collections import deque

def copyme(el):
    n = Element(el.tag, el.attrib)
    n.text = el.text
    n.tail = el.tail
    return n

def depthcopy(root, max_depth=1):
    queue = deque([(root, None, 0)])
    keep = None

    while queue:
      el, parent, depth = queue.popleft()
      if depth == max_depth:
        break

      new_parent = copyme(el)
      if parent is None:
        keep = new_parent
      else:
        parent.append(new_parent)

      # print(etree.tostring(keep))

      queue.extend([(x, new_parent, depth + 1) for x in el])
      # print(el.tag, depth)

    return keep

root = etree.XML('<root><a><b/><c/></a><d><e/></d></root>')
print(etree.tostring(depthcopy(root, 2)))
```